# How do you call a file name defined as list by each name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you call a file name defined as list by each name?

*First, you default the method to import the csv file.

```
def f_read_csv(tgrt_csv):
    trgt_csv_temp = '%s.csv' % (tgrt_csv)
    tgrt_tbl = pd.read_csv("".join([get_csv_path,trgt_csv_temp]))
    return tgrt_tbl
```

*Secondly, using the for csv I tried to bring in the name of each file in list.

```
for name in read_csv_list:
    f_read_csv('%s' %name)
```

**How can I get each csv file in the name of the list?**

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your csv file for us to answer better?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use `list comprehension` to generate dataframes.

```
dfs = [f_read_csv(name) for name in read_csv_list]
```

and use `pd.concat` to concat them

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

and more, use `glob` to generate files list

```
files = glob.glob("/path/to/target/files/*.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. I think you’re asking how to append  '.csv' to the elements of the list. Is that correct?

If so then you can use the `map()` function to achieve it:

```py
z = list(map(lambda ip:(ip+'.csv'),tgrt_csv)
```

Then you can load the contents using `pd.read_csv()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your function, to get the names out, because I am not sure it works, some parts of the puzzle are missing :-).
But I maintained some characteristics like asking for the files extension.
In order to use os.listdir we import os module.

```
import os
```

I've defined my path as a folder in my python working directory and stored 3 csv files in there.

```
path = 'somedir/'
```

Here is your new function:

```
def f_read_csv(tgrt_csv):

  tgrt_tbl = [] #to store file names

    for file in os.listdir(tgrt_csv): #access to the directory

      if file.endswith('.csv'): #checking files with .csv extension
        name_file = os.path.join(tgrt_csv, file)
        tgrt_tbl.append(name_file)

  return tgrt_tbl
```

Then you call the function f_read_csv and pass the path:

```
names = f_read_csv("somedir/")
```

The output, if you print it:

```
['somedir/file 1.csv', 'somedir/file 2.csv', 'somedir/file 3.csv']
```

If you want them as strings you can get them out of the list:

```
for name in names:
    print(name)


somedir/file 1.csv
somedir/file 2.csv
somedir/file 3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

do you meaning read a list of filename by pandas, and transfrom then to dataframe, if all csv file has same format, you can use `dask.dataframe`

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv(f"{get_csv_path}*.csv")
df = ddf.compute()
```

dask is incompatible with pandas.